# Is there a way from p4 command line to shelve local changes without checking out the files in perforce first?

Tags: perforce

Our perforce project has exclusive lock on, so we can't checkout files other people have checked out. Is there a way to bypass checking out the files and shelve the local changes directly?

I've tried using "p4 reconcile" and "p4 print" with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to do this (at least not without circumventing the `+l` protection, which is possible on some server configurations), since `shelve` only operates on open files.

The idea of exclusive-open (`+l`) files is that because it's not possible to merge them, you never want someone making changes that are based on anything other than the latest version (including whatever version someone is currently working on).  So making a shelf of a `+l` file would go against the intent of that (since your shelf would be based on the current depot revision and would not include the other user's changes).

If this is a file where it does make sense to modify it concurrently, it probably should not have the `+l` type.  IMO the `+l` type should be used sparingly or never.  You can ensure that *you* will not need to resolve changes by using a normal `p4 lock`, which allows other users to open and shelve the file at any time but not to submit it until the lock is released; figuring out how to resolve and submit after you've submitted your changes will be *their* problem.

If you don't have control over whether this file uses `+l` and you need to get your changes onto the server, my recommendation would be to branch the file (`+l` doesn't prevent that, even though it probably ought to) and submit/shelve your change to the branch.